# Put the info from a PHP form to a notepad or word

Tags: php, forms, get, copy, submit

My question is if there is a way, like sending the stuff to an email after clicking the submit button to do the same action but creating a `.txt` file or `.doc` file with all the info there like if it was an email. I would really need to create a document with the info everytime someone hit 'submit' so I don't get confused.

To be more clear, enter the `data > submit >` create a file in folder with only that info.

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<?php    
<form name="form1" action="test3.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
 <table width="100%" >

Please enter your Sudent ID: <INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="" NAME = "studentid"><br />
    <br />

    Please select the category that you want to receive on your moval.edu e-mail account.<br /><br />
    <b>Athletics:</b><br><br />
    <b>MEN'S</b><br />

<input type=checkbox name=footb >Football<br>
<input type=checkbox name=bball >Baseball<br>
<input type=checkbox name=basket >Basketball<br>
<input type=checkbox name=cheer >Cheer<br>
<input type=checkbox name=xcountry >Cross Country<br>
<input type=checkbox name=golf >Golf<br>
<input type=checkbox name=lax >Lacrosse<br>
<input type=checkbox name=rodeo >Rodeo<br>
<input type=checkbox name=socc >Soccer<br>
<input type=checkbox name=tennis >Tennis<br>
<input type=checkbox name=track >Track<br>
<input type=checkbox name=volleyb >Volleyball<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wrestl >Wrestling<br><br />

    <b>WOMEN'S</b><br />
<input type=checkbox name=wbasket >Basketball<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wcheer >Cheer<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wxcountry >Cross Country<br>
<input type=checkbox name=dance >Dance<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wgolf >Golf<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wlax >Lacrosse<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wrodeo >Rodeo<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wsocc >Soccer<br>
<input type=checkbox name=softb >Softball<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wtennis >Tennis<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wtrack >Track<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wvolleyb >Volleyball<br>
<input type=checkbox name=wwrestl >Wrestling<br><br />

    <b>STUDENT AFFAIRS ACIVITIES</b><br><br />
    <input type=checkbox name=sudentaff > Sign me up for Student Affairs Activities<br /><br />

    <b>INTERNAIONAL CLUB ACTIVITIES</b><br /><br />
    <input type=checkbox name=intclub > Sign me up for International Club Activities<br /><br />

    <b>HISTORICAL ACTIVITIES</b><br><br />
    <input type=checkbox name=history > Sign me up for Hisorical Activities<br /><br />

    <b>CONTESTS</b><br><br />
    <input type=checkbox name=contests > Sign me up for Contests<br /><br />

    <b>LIBRARY EVENTS</b><br><br />
    <input type=checkbox name=libevents > Sign me up for Library Evens<br /><br />

    <b>VIKING EXCHANGE</b><br /><br />
    <input type=checkbox name=vikexch > Sign me up for Viking Exchange News<br /><br />


</table>


 <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdiAugSAAAAAKzj8jQeUTm4dsYINvJICQIEbenc">
  </script>
  <noscript>
     <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdiAugSAAAAAKzj8jQeUTm4dsYINvJICQIEbenc"
         height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
     <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
     </textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
         value="manual_challenge">
  </noscript>




<input name="cmd_submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
?>
```

---

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "6LdiAugSAAAAAL6unDYarZoKPYHGHgta6lp30vG0";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    header("Location: test41.php");
  }
  ?>






<?php



if ($formSubmitted) {
    $fh = fopen('J:\Off_IT\Internships\info.txt', 'a');

    foreach($formData as $data) {
        fwrite($data . "\n");
    }
}


?>
```

The first is the one with the form, the second one is the action of the first one.

Comment: `$formSubmitted` is not an actual variable, neither is `$formData`. You will have to change the code accordingly. Additonally, the users will be redirected before your code can actually be executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code with pseudo variables:

```
if ($formSubmitted) {
    $fh = fopen('/path/to/file.txt', 'w');

    foreach($formData as $data) {
        fwrite($data . "\n");
    }
}
```

Of course, you would have to figure out a way to create unique filenames (or use `a` instead of `w` when opening the file handle in order to append lines to the file.

Comment: Nothing... Still says the same. 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: What's your code? You can post it as an edit to the question.